# How to set description or title to Facebook photo share with PhotoShareContent in Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing an Android app. In my app, I am integrating Facebook photo share feature. This is my first Android app with Facebook integration. I am able to share photo to user timeline now. But I am having problem with setting description to that image.

This is my Facebook share photo function

```
 private void sharePhotoToFacebook(){

        SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                .setBitmap(shareBitmap)
                .build();

        SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                .addPhoto(photo)
                .build();

        ShareApi.share(content, null);

    }
```

When photo shared it shows like this in timeline

[image]

As you can see there is no description or title. What I want is I want to set title or description. Is there any function can do like below

```
SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                    .addPhoto(photo).setCaption("Description")
                    .build();
```

How can I set title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write setCaption() method as below:

```
 SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
            .setBitmap(shareBitmap)
            .setCaption("Description")
            .build();
```

Note: need to use SDK vertion 4+. Means at least 4.1

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
```

Comment: I cannot access to set captions method

Comment: It is showing error with red line cause setCaption method does not exist.

Comment: Oh ya. My sdk version is too low. I updated it and now I can see that. What about sharing multiples photo like this new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                        .addPhotos(sharePhotos)
                        .build(); . I do not want to set caption for each photo. I want to set one caption for all photos. How can I  get it please?

Comment: Yes you need to use compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'  version of FacebookSdk to get above method.

Comment: I am also having problem with my current code. I shared photos. Then successfully posted to timeline. Then I shared other photos, then secondly shared photos are combined with firstly shared photos as one album. So please how can I separate them?

Comment: @WaiYanHein I' m not sure but photos with same captions might be placed in same album, try to change caption of all photos, it might help.

Answer (score 1):

As per Facebook Platform Policies (2.3) you cannot set caption from your app. Read this note from documentation.

```
setCaption(String)
```

[Sets the user generated caption for the photo. Note that the 'caption' must come from the user, as pre-filled content is forbidden by the Platform Policies (2.3).](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/4.13/class/SharePhoto.Builder/)

Comment: Currently I  used setCaption and it is successful. You mean if my app goes live, it will not work?

Comment: This does not work even if your app is not live. The explanation says it all. Disappointing. Captions are really useful.